# Drupal is not rendering a block view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Good morning,

I have a block named feed-empleo whose machine name I think it is "feed-empleo-block".
[image]

Its url is: /admin/structure/block/manage/views/feed-empleo-block/configure, so that is why I think it's machine name is "feed-empleo-block".

In my node template, I am using:

```
<div class="block block-feed" id="block-feed-empleo">test</div>
```

That is because I think its class and id should be:

```
<div class="block block-{module}" id="block-{module}-{delta}">
```

So, finally, I have created a templated named:

```
views-view--feed-empleo-block.tpl.php
```

I must be doing something wrong because there is nothing in the div tag. But I am not really sure why isn't being shown.

Comment: Go to views -> advance -> Other ->  Theme: Information and rescan your view template file from there. and you can see your custom template there. Check this link for proper info http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/create-template-file-for-views-block

Comment: Hi Hardik, If this is it... http://i.imgur.com/2upvngD.png
Does that mean that I should use views-view--feed-empleo.tpl.php ?

Comment: Yeah but make sure you rescan template file and clear your drupal cache as well.

Comment: Have you clicked on THEME: Information and checked whether your theme file is being used or not? Check this https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/

Comment: @hardiksolanki Could you add an answer in order to accept it?

Comment: @Cod1ngFree Yeah sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `views -> advance -> Other -> Theme: Information` and `rescan your view template file` from there. and you can see your custom template there.

Check this link for proper info:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/create-template-file-for-views-block

Make sure you `rescan template file` and `clear your drupal cache` as well.